# Why is WeakMap clear() method deprecated?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, weakmap

I have been working with [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)s in JavaScript, and after checking the documentation I realized that the `clear` method has been [deprecated / removed from ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap/clear).

What is the reason for this? 
Why force us to do a clear function like:

```
clear() {
  this._weakmap = new WeakMap()
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> “The mapping from weakmap/key pair value can only be observed or
> affected by someone who has both the `WeakMap` and the key. With
> `clear()`, someone with only the `WeakMap` would’ve been able to affect
> the WeakMap-and-key-to-value mapping.”

[Mark Miller](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2014-11/nov-19.md#412-should-weakmapweakset-have-a-clear-method-markm)

The reason for this restriction are security concerns:

> A key property of Weak Maps is the inability to enumerate their keys.
> This is necessary to prevent attackers observing the internal behavior
> of other systems in the environment which share weakly-mapped objects.
> Should the number or names of items in the collection be discoverable
> from the API, even if the values aren't, WeakMap instances might
> create a side channel where one was previously not available.

[tc39wiki](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/weak-map/)

A enumerable `WeakMap` could possibly also affect GC, since you could then observe the GC process indirectly. Thus, to ensure a predictable design `clear` was removed as well.

Comment: If `clear` is functionally identical to creating a new `WeakMap`, then how can it raise any security concerns? Why mention enumerability, when clear doesn't imply it?

Answer (score 5):

It is deprecated because it prevents inverted implementation of `WeakMap`.

See [Removal of WeakMap/WeakSet clear](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/removal-of-weakmap-weakset-clear).

> If WeakMaps/WeakSets are not inspectable (via iteration) and do not have a clear operation, then the inverted implementation technique can be use used. This technique eliminates significant GS complexity.

Inverted implementation description, from the same source:

> design for an inverted implementation:
>
> Every object internally maintains a table (probably a hash table if it contains more than a few elements) that is used to implement WeakMap/Set. Entry in the table is a key/value pair where the key is a WeakMap/Set instance. Values are arbitrary ES values. Let's call such a table an "inverted map" and generically refer to such WeakMaps/Sets as WCs.